# Elementos sumindo quando entra em modo responsivo e só aparece quando clica nele

Tags: html, css, angular

Assim que minha página é carregada, todos os elementos que cabem na tela são renderizados, porém ao descer um pouco a tela, os elementos não são mostrados, somente são renderizados quando clico em cima deles, e quando este elemento é mostrado, outro elemento na parte de cima some (?)

1. Pagina logo quando é carregada mostra todos os elementos que cabem na tela:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

2. Ao descer a página percebo que os elementos não estão sendo mostrados:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

3. Ao clicar em cima, o elemento é renderizado:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Alguém já passou por isso? Eu tentei algumas coisas como:

Verifiquei se as divs estão fechando corretamente onde deveriam;
Verifiquei se existem ids iguais;
Verifiquei se todas as variáveis do ngmodel existe no ts.

To sem saber o que fazer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pra quem se interessar, eu utilizo o material design bootstrap e quando alterei o card deles pra position: sticky, os elementos foram renderizados conforme o esperado. Não entendi muito bem porque deu certo